# ruamel yaml disabling alias for dumping

Tags: python-3.x, yaml, ruamel.yaml

I've been digging through documentation for the past two days and struggling to find any recent example of how to handle the `ignore_aliases()` call.

The config object is a python dict containing the list of dicts. The output below is generated if I disable the `ignore_aliases()` call.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    team = TeamConfig("../TeamConfig.yml")
    config = team.generateSonarConfig()

    with open("../Test.yml", 'w') as f:
        yml = YAML()
        yml.indent(mapping=2, sequence=4, offset=2)
        yml.Representer.ignore_aliases(yml, config)
        yml.dump(config, f)
```

The indentation is great, and the order is preserved, I just need to remove the anchors and aliases:

```
templates:
  - name: freedom
    users:
      - &id001
        name: service-account2
        permissions:
          - browse
          - read
  - name: liberty
    users:
      - *id001
      - *id002
      - name: service-account3
        permissions:
          - browse
          - read
      - name: service-account4
        permissions:
          - browse
          - read
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, I don't think the output you present is complete, as it is invalid
YAML and I certainly hope `ruamel.yaml` did not generate that as shown (if it
did file a bug report with the complete source).

---

I don't know where you got that example from but the method `ignore_aliases()`
is called with a data structure and should return `True` if any aliases should be
ignored. It is not something you call yourself. You can subclass the Representer or monkey-patch that on the RoundTripRepresenter.

The method in `representer.py` should take a data parameter and always return `False`:

```
import sys
from pathlib import Path
import ruamel.yaml

# your output minus the `- *id002` alias that has no corresponding anchor
in_file = Path('Test.yaml')  

# monkey patch:
ruamel.yaml.representer.RoundTripRepresenter.ignore_aliases = lambda x, y: True

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.indent(mapping=2, sequence=4, offset=2)
data = yaml.load(in_file)

yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
templates:
  - name: freedom
    users:
      - name: service-account2
        permissions:
          - browse
          - read
  - name: liberty
    users:
      - name: service-account2
        permissions:
          - browse
          - read
      - name: service-account3
        permissions:
          - browse
          - read
      - name: service-account4
        permissions:
          - browse
          - read
```

Alternatively you can do the somewhat more verbose:

```
import sys
from pathlib import Path
import ruamel.yaml

# your output minus the `- *id002` alias that has no corresponding anchor
in_file = Path('Test.yaml')  

class NonAliasingRTRepresenter(ruamel.yaml.representer.RoundTripRepresenter):
    def ignore_aliases(self, data):
        return True


yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.Representer = NonAliasingRTRepresenter
yaml.indent(mapping=2, sequence=4, offset=2)
data = yaml.load(in_file)

yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives the same output.

Comment: Anthon, appreciate the help. You are right the output I pasted isn't the entire YAML and did so to save some space :) my apologies for any confusion or misrepresentation.

I followed the example with subclassing and that resolved my issues. I was trying to figure out the argument type and had some difficulty for the RoundTripRepresenter so thank you for clarifying. 

I did notice that I wasn't able to find the same exact path `ruamel.yaml.representer.RoundTripRepresenter` for some reason... I am using the latest version of ruamel.

Comment: The `RoundTripRepresenter` is imported from representer.py into `main.py` and that is imported into `__init__.py` in `ruamel.yaml`, not sure why my import would not work for you. Did you use `pip` to install this?

Comment: Yeah I was confused too about that, I do have my own `__init__.py` in the same directory as `main.py` if that matters?

And yep, installed latest via pip install. Python 3.8

Comment: The RoundTripRepresenter `ignore_aliases` method only takes a single parameter (as is shown in the second example), so the lambda in the first example needs to be changed. All I needed was `yaml.representer.ignore_aliases = lambda x: True` after the init call (`yaml = YAML()`). Would be handy if this was an option on the representer (e.g. being able to set `yaml.representer.ignore_all_aliases = True` or so).

Comment: Hi @Anthon, this doesn't appear to work quite right if the anchor is on a string, rather than an object. It replaces the reference but adds an extra anchor, e.g., `{a: &i "X", b: *i}` becomes `{a: &i X, b: &i X}`. Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: I had a look through the `RoundTripRepresenter` code and found this would work `def represent_scalar(self, tag, value, style=None, anchor=None): return super().represent_scalar(tag, value, style)`

Comment: @parched That is entirely possible. The ignore_aliases method replacement was in the original PyYAML code and never affected primitive scalars (string, int, boolean, null) as  anchors/aliases on those were never set internally. What is needed here is a more user-friendly mechanism to control aliases on the `YAML()` instance, allowing for dropping all/keeping all/keep only needed, via a simple attribute setting/method invocation.

Answer (score 0):

This ended up working for me instead.

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

from configure.python.TeamConfig import TeamConfig

class NonAliasingRTRepresenter(ruamel.yaml.RoundTripRepresenter):
    def ignore_aliases(self, data):
        return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    team = TeamConfig("../TeamConfig.yml")
    config = team.generateSonarConfig()

    with open("../Test.yml", 'w') as f:
        yml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
        yml.indent(mapping=2, sequence=4, offset=2)
        yml.Representer = NonAliasingRTRepresenter
        yml.dump(config, f)
```